# Detect random Powerpoint freezes while performing actions

Tags: vb.net, crash, powerpoint, office-interop

I am creating a lot of Powerpoint Slides in a loop, using Interop and VB.NEt 4.0 and I have trouble solving a strange powerpoint crash.

The creation of slides works well in most cases, but sometimes Powerpoint runs into a problem of its own and stops working properly.
Most of the times it just stops responding oder crashes immediately. Detecting this failure is easy, just evaluate the H_Result. But sometimes there is a more challenging failure: Powerpoint stops responding but does not throw an exception. It simply stops working until somebody manually tries to push a button in Powerpoint, which will generate an exception.
But if nobody pushes this button, Powerpoint will stay frozen indefinitely. Due to this condition, my code will never have a chance to evaluate the problem. This is especially annoying if you want to create a huge number of Slides at night and it stops after Slide 50. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem. This whole program runs in an Backgroundworker - so maybe my main thread can ask the bgw every minute or so "are you still alive?" But how to implement this.

Below is a simple Outline of the Backgroundworkercode.

Basically, it's look like this:

```
Dim SlideNumber as Integer =0
Dim PowerpointHasCrashed as Boolean
Dim Slide as pptns.Slide

do while SlideNumber<ListOfSlidesTobeCreated.Count-1 and PowerpointHasCrashed =False

try
   DoStuffWithSlide(ListOfSlidesTobeCreated(SlideNumber))
catch ex as exception
   If ex.message like PowerPointFailue then
      PowerpointHasCrashed =True
   End If    
end try

SlideNumber +=1
end while

If PowerpointHasCrashed =true then
SlideNumber -=1
'Do some Stuff to repair the Damage and start the loop again.
End If
```

Comment: A simple approach could be to expose the SlideNumber value as a public property that can be queried from the main thread. So if it does not increase for a few minutes then something is wrong. But actually from my experience strange PowerPoint behavior is usually caused by third-party software and not PowerPoint itself. So I suggest you check your code and disable any add-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle, i simply used the Backgroundworker.Reportsprogress sub to set a datetime variable to now.
Every 3 minutes a timer checks this variable, if this variable is older than 5 minutes, Powerpoint will be killed and restartet.
Because every finished slides causes reportsprogress to increase, this works very well.